# str_replace using an array

Tags: php, str-replace

Trying to understand code similar to the following.

```
$line = 'This line has a cat ant goat dog monkey rat and ape';
$animals = array( 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'rat' );

$count = 1;
while ($count) 
{
    $line = str_replace( $animals, '', $line, $count );
}

echo $line;
```

I can't seem to understand the necessity for a loop here. The following seems to give the same results.

```
$line = 'This line has a cat ant goat dog monkey rat and ape';
$animals = array( 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'rat' );

$line = str_replace( $animals, '', $line, $count );

echo $line;
```

So, why the loop... am I missing the plot here? Or does it have some added benefit?

Comment: the looped code is written by ex JavaScript developer where str_replace replaces only the first occurance.

Comment: the loop doesn't make sense, and there is no break

Comment: No, the loop looks like it was done because the manual for `str_replace()` wasn't read or wasn't understood.

Comment: Oh... I wouldn't have guessed that :)

Comment: There's a comparable example in [the `str_replace()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) all the vowels are replaced with an empty string by array.

Comment: The `$count` variable is unneeded (and possibly harmful) in the non-loop version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that after the replacement of the word, the resulting string may be repeated.

Example:

```
$line = 'aaaaaaaaa';
$animals = array( 'aaa');

$count = 1;
while ($count)
{
    $line = str_replace( $animals, 'a', $line, $count );
}

echo $count . '<br>' . $line; //result a

$line = 'aaaaaaaaa';
$animals = array( 'aaa');

$line = str_replace( $animals, 'a', $line, $count );

echo $count . '<br>' . $line; //result aaa
```

Comment: First iteration from my example with 'aaaaaaaaa' (while):
1) line = aaa, count=3; 
2) line = a, count=1;
3) line = a, count=0; (while 0) if 0 then break from loop;

Comment: Gorchak that was excellent! Although, it took me a bit of time to fully grasp everything, the penny eventually dropped.

Answer (score -1):

Let us understand the $count variable in str_replace first.

It represent the number of times of replacement of matched keywords.

In above case, at the first loop, $count shall equals to 4.

As $count equals to 4, the while loop continues. The str_replace line will run again.

At the second loop, at the second run of str_replace, there shall be no replacement at all. $count will also become 0 since there is no matches at all. All keywords have been replaced at the first time.

So in my humble opinion, the second loop is some kind of unnecessary prevention, in case the str_replace do not function well at the first time. Otherwise, the second loop is totally meaningless and useless, because PHP seldom make such a mistake at this functional layer.